# How can I find the next node higher value than a selected number in a Binary Search Tree in C?

Tags: c, search, data-structures, binary-search-tree, function-definition

For example: If my Tree data have the nodes with following values = (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60);

And if 45 is selected, then I must return the node with the next hight value. (if 45, then 50).

Must return NULL if there's no higher value.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Tree {
    int x;
    struct Tree *left, *right;
};
typedef struct Tree Tree;

Tree * create_empty_tree() {
   return NULL;
}

Tree * insert(Tree *t, int x) {
    if (t == NULL) {
        t = (Tree *) malloc(sizeof(Tree));
        t->x= x;
        t->left = NULL;
        t->right = NULL;
    } else if (x < t->x) {
        t->left = insert(t->left, x);
    } else {
        t->right = insert(t->right, x);
    }
}

void print_in_order(Tree *arv) {
   if (arv != NULL) {
      print_in_order(arv->left);
      printf("%d, ", arv->x);
      print_in_order(arv->right);
   }
}

Tree * find_node_higher_than_x(Tree *t, int x) {
     //toDo
}

int main() {
    Tree *t = create_empty_tree();
    t = insert(t, 2);
    t = insert(t, 8);
    t = insert(t, 10);
    t = insert(t, 4);
    t = insert(t, 6);
    t = insert(t, 7);
    t = insert(t, 1);
    
    print_in_order(t);
    
    Tree *node = find_node_higher_than_x(t, 5); //Must return node with x == 6
}
```

There's a way to make it?

Comment: You forgot to post the complete program which constructs the mentioned tree.

Comment: Do you know how to find the node (if it exists) that exactly matches the searched-for value?  If you can write that code, adjusting it so it finds the next-higher value shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: You could do this with a for loop going through your tree and having an if statement where you look if the current node you are on is inferior or equal to the value you are looking for and the next node equal or greater than your value. There are other more efficient ways but this is probably the easiest

Comment: Done. I've added the complete program in the post...

Comment: @Carlim I have already showed you a  solution. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First correct the `insert` method so it always *returns* a node.

Your function could work like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Tree {
    int x;
    struct Tree *left, *right;
};
typedef struct Tree Tree;

// Create a separate function for constructing a tree node
Tree * create_tree(int x) { 
    Tree *t = (Tree *) malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    t->x= x;
    t->left = NULL;
    t->right = NULL; 
    return t;
}

Tree * create_empty_tree() {
    return NULL;
}

Tree * insert(Tree *t, int x) {
    if (t == NULL) {
        t = create_tree(x);
    } else if (x < t->x) {
        t->left = insert(t->left, x);
    } else {
        t->right = insert(t->right, x);
    }
    return t; // Must return it!
}

void print_in_order(Tree *arv) {
    if (arv != NULL) {
        print_in_order(arv->left);
        printf("%d, ", arv->x);
        print_in_order(arv->right);
    }
}

Tree * find_node_higher_than_x(Tree *t, int x) {
    if (t == NULL) return NULL;
    if (x >= t->x) return find_node_higher_than_x(t->right, x);
    Tree * temp = find_node_higher_than_x(t->left, x);
    return temp != NULL ? temp : t;
}

int main() {
    Tree *t = create_empty_tree();
    t = insert(t, 2);
    t = insert(t, 8);
    t = insert(t, 10);
    t = insert(t, 4);
    t = insert(t, 6);
    t = insert(t, 7);
    t = insert(t, 1);
    
    print_in_order(t);

    // Loop to repeatedly call this function and so traverse the tree
    Tree *node = find_node_higher_than_x(t, 0);
    while (node != NULL) {
        printf("\n%d", node->x);
        node = find_node_higher_than_x(t, node->x);
    }

    return 0; // Must return an int
}
```